# How do you shim FirstOrDefault in EntityFramework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unit-testing, microsoft-fakes

Using Microsoft Fakes and Entityframework, I am trying to create a shim for FirstOrDefault().  I have a method I would like to unit test that looks like this:

```
protected override v_Titles GetEntityByKey(Guid key)
    {
        var result = Context.v_Titles.FirstOrDefault(t => t.Id == key);
        if ( result == null )
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Which is called by a public method Get(Guid key).

I set up fakes and shimed the database and the v_Titles collection:

```
public void SetUp()
    {
        _titles = new List<v_Titles>
        {
            new v_Titles
            {
                Id = new Guid(1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
                PostedDate = new DateTime(2013,1,1),
                Title = "2013-01-01"
            },
            new v_Titles
            {
                Id = new Guid(2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
                PostedDate = new DateTime(2013,5,23),
                Title = "2013-05-23"
            },
            new v_Titles
            {
                Id = new Guid(3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
                PostedDate = new DateTime(2013,8,10),
                Title = "2013-08-10"
            }
        };


        _shimTitles = new ShimDbSet<v_Titles>();
        _shimTitles.Bind(_titles);

        ...

        _databaseShim = new shimDatabaseEntities();
        _databaseShim.v_TitlesGet = () => _shimTitles.Instance;

        _target = new TitlesController
        {
            Context = _databaseShim.Instance
        };
```

Further where the ... is I've tried the following shims to get FirstOrDefault to work:

```
            System.Linq.Fakes.ShimEnumerableQuery<v_Titles>.AllInstances.GetEnumerator = (a) =>
            { return _titles.GetEnumerator(); };
        System.Linq.Fakes.ShimQueryable.FirstOrDefaultOf1IQueryableOfM0<v_Titles>((a) =>
            {
                return _titles.FirstOrDefault();
            });
        databaseEntities.AllInstances.v_TitlesGet = (a) => _shimTitles.Instance;
```

My unit test looks like this:

```
        [TestMethod]
    public void Get_ReturnsOneItem_Test()
    {
        using (ShimsContext.Create())
        {
            var expected = new Guid(2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
            SetUp();
            var result = _target.Get(expected);
        }
    }
```

When running the test I get the following exception on the .FirstOrDefault() call.

> System.ArgumentNullException was unhandled by user code
>     HResult=-2147467261
>     Message=Value cannot be null.
>   Parameter name: arguments
>     Source=System.Core
>     ParamName=arguments
>     StackTrace:
>          at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.RequiresCanRead(Expression expression, String paramName)
>          at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.ValidateOneArgument(MethodBase method, ExpressionType nodeKind, Expression arg, ParameterInfo pi)
>          at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.ValidateArgumentTypes(MethodBase method, ExpressionType nodeKind, ReadOnlyCollection`1& arguments)
>          at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Call(Expression instance, MethodInfo method, IEnumerable`1 arguments)
>          at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Call(Expression instance, MethodInfo method, Expression[] arguments)
>          at System.Linq.Queryable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 predicate)
>          at WebSite.Web.Controllers.Api.TitlesController.GetEntityByKey(Guid key) in Controllers\Api\TitlesController.cs:line 42
>          at System.Web.Http.OData.EntitySetController`2.Get(TKey key)
>          at WebSite.Web.Tests.TitlesController_Tests.Get_ReturnsOneItem_Test() in TitlesController_Tests.cs:line 96
>     InnerException:

How do I get the FirstOrDefault return something?  It does not even have to execute the query, all I want to test is that I am calling FirstOrDefault and returning the value it retuns or throws the exception when it returns null.

Comment: Am I right in thinking you are trying to mock `EntityFramework`?

Comment: This seems off. You'd want to mock the `Context.v_Titles` part, not the Linq/EF part. Next thing would be "how to mock `System.String`"

Comment: I do have Context.v_Titles mocked, as is shown in my code.  I bind the v_Titles to a collection and am getting that collection returned when I look at Context.v_Titles.  It only blows up on FirstOrDefault() calls.

Comment: Agree with @HenkHolterman. This is one of the reason that I don't like the Fakes framework. It forces you to do these kind of things. You would not want to go far as stubbing the FirstOrDefault(). The API is part of Linq and it is well tested. So you can assume it always provide the FirstOrDefault from a given collection. The  collection/one level up is the one you should stub.

Comment: @Raj: Fakes in no way forces you to do things like this. This is stuff you should never do in the first place. In this code, I see no stubs, which likely means a total lack of DI, resulting in shims being required. Since it looks like he's simply wrapping EF, and hiding the mechanics behind it, this doesn't really qualify as a unit test - and it's the exact opposite of DI.

Comment: Thanks all for the feedback.  I will re-think my approach.

Comment: @AlexBeisley I disagree, I think you miss my point. "Force" may not be the right choice of word. But it definitely tempted take the wrong path imo. Don't want to go into detail, but I have seen many, especially new devs who don't know the testability aspects, try to stub everything with Fakes. Including .NET framework methods. I agree even some developers without any powerful isolation framework trying stub unnecessary method. Having Fakes in the hand make these tasks easier. But this is not the case for people who understand the principals of testable design.

Comment: @Raj, I agree with you to some extent, but there's a reason we use C# rather than Java. The Java way is to keep you from shooting yourself in the foot, whereas the C# way is to give you tools. Knowing when you should use shims is on par with knowing when you should use value types or unsafe blocks.

Comment: So, in line with the comments above, where should I be using stubs instead of shims?  I'd like unit testability of my EntityControllerClass implementation, but it is by nature tightly coupled to the Entity sets that it returns.

Comment: @Steve: I think the larger problem is how you're structuring your code. I'm seeing static access of a dependency in a non-public method, which is a fairly terrible thing to do, but ultimately the biggest problem is that you're trying to not only unit test a non-public member, you're trying to unit test a member which relies on data access. That's a whole different level from unit testing.

Comment: Entity Framework doesn't provide the `FirstOrDefault()` you're using, so why should the fake? Provide an implementation of `IQueryable<v_Titles>`.

Answer (score -2):

Reading your post i think that i came across the same issue, i'm not going to copy and paste the solution that i found and work for me, instead i give you the URL :

http://mylifeandcode.blogspot.com/2012/10/unit-testing-with-mock-entity-framework.html

Have fun!!!

Comment: While this link may answer the question, you should avoid link-only answers.

Comment: It's actually not as bad to copy and paste, then provide your link & name of site as a source. However, putting something in your own words and applying it specifically to the question is significantly better. For more information, see [answer]. Thank you!

Comment: Downvoting since the question is asked for Microsoft fakes